Feedback on a number theory word problem

Two partners owned a livestock business. They decided to sell a herd
of cows. After some negotiation, it happened that the price per cow
(in units of currency) was equal to the total number of cows sold.
With the proceeds, they purchased a flock of adult sheep, each priced
at 10 units of currency, and a lamb. After dividing the value evenly
between themselves, one person ended up with one more adult sheep than
the other; the other person received the lamb and an additional sum of
money to compensate for the remaining difference. Given that this
additional sum of money is a whole number (in units of currency).
Determine:

The additional sum of money
The minimum number of cows sold
The minimum number of sheep purchased.


The answer is 2, 6 , and 3.
EDIT: In light of @lulu 's comment, I've edited my solution and updated my questions as follows:

Let $C$ be the number of cows sold, $N$ be the number of adult sheep, $p$ be the price of the lamb, and $s$ be the amount of the sum of money.
The proceeds were used to purchase the sheep, so:
\begin{align*}
C^2 = 10N + p \qquad (1)
\end{align*}
Let $x, y$ be the number of sheep each partner received, with $y$ be the number of sheep received by the partner who also got the lamb. We have:
\begin{align*}
x + y &= N \\
x &= y + 1 \\
\implies N &= 2y + 1 \qquad (2)
\end{align*}
They divided the value equally between themselves, so:
\begin{align*}
10(y +1) - s &= 10y + p + s \\
\implies p &= 10 - 2s \qquad (3)
\end{align*}
Plug $(2)$ and $(3)$ into $(1),$ we have:
\begin{align*}
C^2 &= 20(y +1) - 2s
\end{align*}
$s$ is the compensating sum for the remaining difference $\implies s < 10.$
$p > 0 \implies 2s < 10.$
We have: $C^2 \equiv \{-19, -16, -15, -11, -4\} \pmod{20} \implies 2s = 4$ or $s = 2.$
$C^2 = 20(y + 1) - 4$
The number of sheep: $N = 2y + 1.$
At this point I'm not sure why $C \geq 6$ and $N \geq 3.$ That appears to be the  case if $y > 0$ or $N > 1$. Clearly, $y = 0$ gives $C \geq 4$ and $N \geq 1.$ Is it because it's a flock of sheep so $N > 1?$

I can't follow your first step.  If $x,y$ are the numbers of sheep each partner gets then $x+y=N$.  How could they get more sheep than the total number of sheep?

@lulu I thought the lamb is also a sheep...

The problem statement clearly differentiates between the sheep and the lamb.

@lulu I think you're right. I do think the problem statement could have been more explicit about which type of sheep one had more than the other, or just sheep in general. I'm not a native speaker so the current phrasing might have been sufficiently clear.

I agree with you.  As you are aware,  a "lamb" is definitely also a "sheep", just as a "kitten" is a "cat" or a "child" is a "person".  It's fine when they refer to "adult sheep", but they drop the "adult" at some points and it's not unreasonable to imagine that the omission has significance.  To avoid ambiguity, I'd have used a goat instead of a lamb.  But I'm pretty sure my reading is the one they intended.

@lulu Thanks! I reddid the solution in light of your comment and the updated solution matches the key. However, I'm not sure why $y$ must be greater than $1$, as explained in the updated post. Do you have any thoughts on this?

I also realized my mistake in the original solution: the person who gave the money lost $s,$ which I didn't account for.
